# How to get the centroid in Louvain method in python?

Tags: python, numpy, networkx

I constructed a graph from my cosine similarity matrix, and apply 'Louvain' community detection on it as follows.

Sample of cosine similarity matrix:

```
array([[ 1.        ,  0.40824829,  0.40824829],
       [ 0.40824829,  1.        ,  0.33333333],
       [ 0.40824829,  0.33333333,  1.        ]])

# S as adjacency matrix (sims is my cosine similarity matrix)
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(sims)

# Louvain method for community detection
partition = community.best_partition(G)
```

Now I want to calculate the centroid (as an average) of all the identified communities (e.g., using np.average) and find the data point that is nearest to the centroid (based on cosine similarity values) for each community.

As I am new to these community detection algorithms, I am still figuring out how to do it. Please help me.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "centroid"? Do the nodes in your network have spatial locations associated with them? In that case, just take the mean of your x coordinates and y coordinates of all nodes pertaining to a module.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I did the same in DBSCAN using centroid = np.average(cluster_samples, axis=0). However, I am very new to networkxand struggling to do this. Can you please elaborate your opinion?

Comment: Nodes in a network need not have a spatial location associated with them. E.g. in social network science you think about graphs where the nodes are people and the links are relationships (e.g. friendships). You might be able to detect different "circles" of friends, but there is no notion of a "centroid" for such a circle of friends. In your network, the nodes seem to have a "spatial" coordinates attached to them. But those are in some sense independent of any network analysis.

Comment: However, you can use the `partition` to separate your nodes into different groups, and then get a the average for each group. It's hard to write that code, however, without knowing the dimensionality of your space (aka the length of the vectors that you feed into your cosine similarity).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed comment. My cosine matrix is around 120x120 size. I updated my question with a small sample of a cosine matrix. Please let me know what are the other details that are important about my data to decide a suitable approach.

Comment: It would help if you could provide a simple input and what the expected output would be.  I (and I believe others) still do not understand what you mean by "centroid".  I don't even know if you want the answer to be a node or a number.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. What I meant is, consider the spatial position of the nodes in each cluster, calculate the possible center of it and find the nearest node to the center. I am new to this area and I do not have a clear idea if it is possible to do it. Can you please tell me, if my idea is correct?